# type safety - all_of/ any_of/ none_of for std::tuple

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++17

So I started to implement some algorithms that mimic the behaviour of the STL algorithms but with a heterogeneous container a.k.a std::tuple.

```
template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename Tuple>
bool all_of(UnaryPredicate&& p, Tuple&& t) noexcept
{
    return std::apply([&p](auto&& ...xs){ return (p(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)) && ...); }, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}

template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename Tuple>
bool any_of(UnaryPredicate&& p, Tuple&& t) noexcept
{
    return std::apply([&p](auto&& ...xs){ return (p(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)) || ...); }, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}

template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename Tuple>
bool none_of(UnaryPredicate&& p, Tuple&& t) noexcept
{
    return std::apply([&p](auto&& ...xs){ return !(p(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)) || ...); }, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}
```

All of these work fine if you use a UnaryPredicate that returns a boolean. But what if it doesn't? How can ensure that UnaryPredicate returns a boolean when it's invoked with each of the elements of the tuple? Also how can I check if UnaryPredicate actually doesn't throw any exceptions.

I know there are type traits like 'is_nothrow_invocable' and 'invoke_result', but all of these require the types of the elements the tuple contains. Do I really have to use the "algorithm_impl" pattern?

```
namespace impl
{
    template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename Tuple, auto ...Is>
    bool all_of_impl(UnaryPredicate&& p, Tuple&& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) noexcept
    {
        return std::apply([&p](auto&& ...xs){ return (p(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)) && ...); }, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
    }
}

template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename Tuple>
bool all_of(UnaryPredicate&& p, Tuple&& t) noexcept
{
    return impl::all_of_impl(std::forward<UnaryPredicate>(p), std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>>{});
}
```

Now I can do something like this:

```
std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<UnaryPredicate>, std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::decay_t<Tuple>>>, bool>...>, bool>
```

But is that really the way to go?

**EDIT :**

Okay as always I overcomplicated things. I think I found an acceptable solution:

```
template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename Tuple>
struct helper;

template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename Tuple>
struct helper2;

template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename ...Ts>
struct helper<UnaryPredicate, std::tuple<Ts...>>
    : std::bool_constant<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<bool, std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<UnaryPredicate>, std::decay_t<Ts>>>...>>
{};

template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename ...Ts>
struct helper2<UnaryPredicate, std::tuple<Ts...>>
    : std::bool_constant<std::conjunction_v<std::is_nothrow_invocable<std::decay_t<UnaryPredicate>, std::decay_t<Ts>>...>>
{};

template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename Tuple>
inline constexpr auto helper_v{ helper<UnaryPredicate, Tuple>::value };

template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename Tuple>
inline constexpr auto helper2_v{ helper2<UnaryPredicate, Tuple>::value };


template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename Tuple>
std::enable_if_t<helper_v<UnaryPredicate, Tuple>, bool> all_of(UnaryPredicate&& p, Tuple&& t) noexcept(helper2_v<UnaryPredicate, Tuple>)
{
    return std::apply([&p](auto&& ...xs){ return (p(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)) && ...); }, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}

template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename Tuple>
std::enable_if_t<helper_v<UnaryPredicate, Tuple>, bool> any_of(UnaryPredicate&& p, Tuple&& t) noexcept(helper2_v<UnaryPredicate, Tuple>)
{
    return std::apply([&p](auto&& ...xs){ return (p(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)) || ...); }, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}

template<typename UnaryPredicate, typename Tuple>
std::enable_if_t<helper_v<UnaryPredicate, Tuple>, bool> none_of(UnaryPredicate&& p, Tuple&& t) noexcept(helper2_v<UnaryPredicate, Tuple>)
{
    return std::apply([&p](auto&& ...xs){ return !(p(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)) || ...); }, std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}
```

Comment: The only thing that the naive implementation accepts and the enable_if'd implementation rejects are return types that overload `operator||`, so why bother?

Comment: It appears you have 2 questions: How to ensure that the UnaryPredicate passed will return a `bool` for each type, and how to check if the UnaryPredicate is `noexcept` for each type. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that's correct @AndyG

Comment: btw this is purely educational purpose, so you can safely assume I don't know all the stuff there is to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an even better solution than my previous edit :)

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename UnaryFunction, typename ...Types>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<std::invoke_result_t<UnaryFunction, Types>, bool>...>, bool> AllOf(UnaryFunction&& p, std::tuple<Types...>&& t) noexcept(std::conjunction_v<std::is_nothrow_invocable<UnaryFunction, Types>...>)
{
    return std::apply([&](auto&& ...xs) constexpr { return (p(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)) && ...); }, std::forward<std::tuple<Types...>>(t));
}

template<typename UnaryFunction, typename ...Types>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<std::invoke_result_t<UnaryFunction, Types>, bool>...>, bool> AnyOf(UnaryFunction&& p, std::tuple<Types...>&& t) noexcept(std::conjunction_v<std::is_nothrow_invocable<UnaryFunction, Types>...>)
{
    return std::apply([&](auto&& ...xs) constexpr { return (p(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)) || ...); }, std::forward<std::tuple<Types...>>(t));
}

template<typename UnaryFunction, typename ...Types>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<std::invoke_result_t<UnaryFunction, Types>, bool>...>, bool> NoneOf(UnaryFunction&& p, std::tuple<Types...>&& t) noexcept(std::conjunction_v<std::is_nothrow_invocable<UnaryFunction, Types>...>)
{
    return std::apply([&](auto&& ...xs) constexpr { return !(p(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)) || ...); }, std::forward<std::tuple<Types...>>(t));
}

int main()
{  
    std::cout 
        << std::boolalpha 
        << AllOf([](auto&& x){ return x; }, std::make_tuple(true, true, true)) << "\n"
        << AnyOf([](auto&& x){ return x; }, std::make_tuple(false, false, true)) << "\n"
        << NoneOf([](auto&& x){ return x; }, std::make_tuple(false, false, false)) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

template<class UnaryPredicate, class Tuple>
auto all_of(UnaryPredicate&& p, Tuple&& t)
RETURNS(
  std::apply(
    [&p](auto&& ...xs){
      return (p(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)) && ...);
    },
    std::forward<Tuple>(t)
  )
)
```

etc

Comment: @Yamahari It copies whatever you pass it and repeats it 3 times in those 3 `__VA_ARGS__` spots.  What confuses you?

Comment: I never use macros in my code :) what is __VA_ARGS__ ?

Comment: @Yamahari When you have `#define macro(...) __VA_ARGS__`, `macro(blah, foo, bar)` expands to `blah, foo, bar` -- `__VA_ARGS__` token is replaced by every argument to `macro`.  I use it here because C preprocessor macros do not understand modern C++ template based `,`s, and consider `foo< int, double >` to be two arguments `foo< int` and `double >`.  In this case, I repeat the return expression 3 times, once for `noexcept`, once for SFINAE and return type, and once to actually return it.  If the expression is invalid, this overload is ignored, which is a friendly error.